# Safari not displaying HTML5 video(already added mime types)

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

I've searched everywhere I can think of. Thanks in advance.
I have already tried adding the codec attributes and I have added 
`AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm`

to my .htaccess file.
All other browsers, including IE, display the video correctly. Safari just gives me the fallback.
Here is the code :

```html
<video controls="controls">

<!-- Provide mp4(h.264), ogg, and webm -->
  
    <source src="_video/lgit01.m4v" type="video/mp4" />        <!-- Safari and IE - Put this first due to issues with the IOS                                                                       not cycling down this list. -->
    <source src="_video/lgit01.webm" type="video/webm" />      <!-- Higher quality than ogg. The browsers that support ogg also                                                                     support webm -->
    <source src="_video/lgit01.ogv" type="video/ogg" />        <!-- Supported by Chrome, Firefox, and Opera - Not IE or Safari -->


    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="eh5v.files/html5video/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;">
        <param name="movie" value="eh5v.files/html5video/flashfox.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;poster=eh5v.files/html5video/lgit_-_01.jpg&amp;src=lgit_-_01.m4v" />
        <embed src="eh5v.files/html5video/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;"  flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;poster=eh5v.files/html5video/lgit_-_01.jpg&amp;src=lgit_-_01.m4v"   allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />

    </object>

<p>your browsers don't support this shit</p>

</video>
```

I have also tried adding a .mp4 vid to the source, on top of .m4v. I have commented out and deleted the flash embed to rule that out. What could possibly be wrong with this? I have the latest version of safari. I pointed safari to youtube and got a page saying "Oops, your web browser is no longer supported". It gives me a fallback link. Can someone please tell me what is going on?

 
Thanks for your time.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question, stack overflow revealed more related items in the sidebar, and I found the solution. It was to simply update Quicktime. Thanks